# SAS - Fill in null values for numeric variables but not dates

Tags: date, sas

I use the following to fill in null values for numeric variables with 0, but this does it for date variables as well. How can I fill in null values only for non-date numeric variables?

```
data mydataset;
set mydataset;
    array myarray _numeric_;
    do over myarray;
    if myarray=. then myarray=0;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: In SAS date variables are numeric variables. So you need a way to identify the date variables. Do your date variables have a date format attached (e.g.  Mmddyy10.)?  That could be a way to identify them.

Comment: Further to @Quentin's answer, look up the `vformat` function to get the format for each of your array variables. Also `do over` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent post on SAS Communities about determining if a variable is a date or not. It's available [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Determine-if-a-variable-contains-a-SAS-date-value/td-p/154851). Your question isn't trivial, as you shouldn't forget about user-defined formats which can also behave like date formats (`proc format`). Let's suppose that all your date variables are of one format.

```
data test;
    format x y z datetime8.;

    x = .;
    y = .;
    z = .;
run;

%macro get_vars_format(lib, tab, fmt);
    proc sql noprint;
        select name into :names separated by ' '
        from sashelp.vcolumn
        where libname = "&lib." and
        memname = "&tab." and
        format eq "&fmt.";
    quit;

    %put Names: &names.;

    data work.test;
        set &lib..&tab.;

        %let i = 1;
        %let name = %scan(&names., &i., %str( ));

        %do %while(&name. ne );
            if &name. eq . then &name = 0;
            output;

            %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
            %let name = %scan(&names., &i., %str( ));
        %end;
    run;
%mend get_vars_format;

%get_vars_format(lib=WORK, tab=TEST, fmt=DATETIME8.);
```

This macro takes three arguments:'

- library name,
- data set name,
- and desired format name.

I am saving all the variables names into a macro-variable (they are separated by a space sign) and in a next step, I am iterating this in a loop (note `i` and `name` macro-variables). For every row, if a value of any variable with a given format is equal to `.` then replace it with `0`. Note that if a variable has a date format, `0` will be treated as a `Jan 01, 1960`, as that's the first day in SAS date value convention.